# DAX finding the Max Sum and return a related value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have been stuck on something for a while. This is essentially what my data looks like:

```
String  Begin Measure (m)   End Measure (m) Length (m)  Date of Test    Tool for Test
Red 0   5   5   18-03-2020  A
Red 5   7   2   18-03-2020  A
Red 7   10  3   18-03-2020  A
Red 0   5   5   01-01-2021  A
Red 5   7   2   01-01-2021  A
Red 7   10  3   01-01-2021  B
Blue    0   3   3   07-05-2019  B
Blue    3   5   2   07-05-2019  B
Blue    5   8   3   07-05-2019  B
Blue    8   11  3   07-05-2019  B
Blue    0   3   3   16-01-2021  C
Blue    3   5   2   16-01-2021  C
Blue    5   8   3   16-01-2021  C
Blue    8   11  3   16-01-2021  C
```

I have one page where you right-click the string name to drill down into a second page which will show the latest Date of Test as well as the Tool used and this is the measure I used:

```
Last Test =
"Date: "
    & MAX ( Sheet1[Date of Test] )
    & "Tool: "
    & LOOKUPVALUE (
        Sheet1[Tool for Test],
        Sheet1[Date of Test], MAX ( Sheet1[Date of Test] )
    )
```

This works fine except for when you are looking at the Red string and see that for the date 01-01-2021, one section of the string is showing a different tool. This data is incorrect but it's what I have to work with.

My solution was to display the tool that makes up the most length of the string. So essentially I want to take the sum of length for all distinct tool types and show the tool type with the max sum in my measure. I'm struggling a lot with this. This is another measure I tried that didn't work either:

```
Test =
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE (
            Sheet1,
            Sheet1[Tool for Test],
            "Tool", Sheet1[Tool for Test],
            "Length", SUM ( Sheet1[Length (m)] )
        ),
        [Length] = MAX ( [Length] )
    ),
    "Tool", [Tool]
)
```

Please help. Here a link to download the Power BI file:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Anf9uNxnnfcqkmGCTQwv9pdwwebZ?e=mLmwx1
and the Excel sheet:
[https://1drv.ms/x/s!Anf9uNxnnfcqkl7osgfpBtSke2GN?e=clAFwp](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Anf9uNxnnfcqkl7osgfpBtSke2GN?e=clAFwp%C2%A0)